# How to do PHP preg_replace to remove all urlencoded % values?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove all %** from a string that has been urlencoded. I figured using this regular expression "%[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}" or this "%[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]" would do it but it does not work. What should I do to just plain remove all values from a string that are put there using urlencode. Although I do not want to remove the + sign.

Comment: Why would you want to remove them? They're part of the URL...

Comment: Well someone helped me out it was I needed it to be "/%[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well regardless of whether I should be doing this or not the regular expression needed to be "/%[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]/". The problem was not having the / in there on both ends to act as a delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not just [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) them?

Comment: Well what I was looking to do is remove all the items that are not url safe as is. I didn't want to decode them just remove them.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can urlencode a %. sounds like you should just urlencode whatever comes in. Enter a % into a text box that sends data via get and look at your address bar.

Comment: Here's a good reason to do it the way @Bobbake4 is suggesting: If your creating an SEO friendly URL to use with a .htaccess redirect based on a users input into a text field. You don't want urlencoded % values in your URL.